# Dotnetnuke URL tracking

Tags: sql, dotnetnuke

I have a DNN (5) internal website that I need track URL's.  I am unable to use any external analytics (Google or otherwise), so I have to rely on the internal installation as-is.  I have also tried a tracking tool, but it does not give me what I need, which is really just raw page and user info.   I have also tried to look at the [UrlLog], [Urls] and [UrlTracking] tables, but even though I am navigating pages, nothing is listed.  The [eventlog] is logging events, so I know I am on the right site.  I don't necessarily want to create new tables and log event separately if DNN does log it anyway.   I would prefer to just be able to query it directly via SQL (or via the reports module).

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the SITE LOG in host settings, that will start to track a lot of information in DNN, by default it is set to 0 days, which won't store any history.

For existing portals, you will need to go into the individual portals settings and update the SITE log to also reflect the correct number of days.  HOST is only used for new sites created.

Comment: Sorry, I did forget that. The Host setting is for NEW portals that get created, existing sites need the site setting. Been so long since I have used that, I completely forgot :D